# Add subdocument log4mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j

I am working with log4j to extract information during the execution. I am interested in storing such an information into a database. In particular, I have choose MongoDB and I am using log4mongo.

Everything is okay, I execute the application and I am able to collect the information into MongoDB, the problem is that I want to log the information with a specific structure, not as a String. That is, I want to generate a sub-document.

The problem Exception is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
   {"{ \"Key1\" : \"value1\" , \"Key2\" : \"value2\"}"}
```

The log4j.properties file I have written is the following:

```
   log4j.rootLogger=debug, MongoDB
   log4j.appender.MongoDB=org.log4mongo.MongoDbPatternLayoutAppender
   log4j.appender.MongoDB.hostname=localhost
   log4j.appender.MongoDB.port=27017
   log4j.appender.MongoDB.databaseName=db
   log4j.appender.MongoDB.collectionName=coll
   log4j.appender.MongoDB.layout=org.log4mongo.MongoDbPatternLayout
   log4j.appender.MongoDB.layout.ConversionPattern={"message":%m}
```

I call log.debug as follows:

```
private void extract() {
     BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();

     obj.put("Key1", "value1");
     obj.put("Key2", "value2");

     LOGGER.debug(obj);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to give MDC a try instead of stuffing all this into the message. It seems like log4mongo picks those up and puts them into the resulting Mongo document.